# SQL - UTC Date Time Conversion

Tags: sql, timezone, utc

Transactions date time in our application are captured in UTC format. 
I need help in expiring the transactions based on local date time.

Example Scenario:

Points Expiration Date:

```
Local Time: 2019-07-17 13:55:22.317
UTC Time: 2019-07-17 08:25:22.317
```

How do I expire the points @2019-07-17 15:00:00.000 - As the expire engine (which runs based on UTC) is still not reached that time yet.

The expiration service runs in CST server and may not expire the points which are until UTC reaches that time. :(

What Am I missing here.?

Comment: Which database engine and version?

Comment: SQL 2018... But If my engine runs at CST., how would I expire the points specific to that time zone...? Should I track UTC as well as corresponding local time as two different fields. ..?

Comment: You need to track the transaction time zone, and evaluate the expiration time relative to that  as per answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2017 and up supports [at time zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

This allows  you to evaluate a local date time to your target time zone

```
select getdate() at time zone 'UTC'
```

Comment: Yes.  This isn't wrong, however if all one needs is UTC then you can simply call `getutcdate()` or `sysutcdatetime()`.  `at time zone` can be used for *other* time zones.